# How to get an image that dragged and dropped from the browser to the DropArea QML component

Tags: drag-and-drop, qml

I'm using the `DropArea` component to transfer files using the Drag&Drop mechanism to my application. The following test code works fine with files located on the system:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    DropArea {
        id: dropArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onEntered: {
            drag.accepted = drag.hasUrls
        }
        onDropped: {
            // Use files through drop.urls
            drop.accept()
        }
    }
}
```

In `onEntered` I accept the `DragEvent` if it contains urls, and in `onDropped` I can use urls to work with dropped files.

But also I need to accept images from the browser through DropArea. At the same time, since the images dragged from the browser do not exist in the file system, I expect to receive raw image data with which I create the image file myself.

The problem is that the `DragEvent drop` from `dropped` signal does not have such data. This can be verified with the following logging:

```
onDropped: {
    console.log("drop.urls: " + drop.urls)
    console.log("drop.html: " + drop.html)
    console.log("drop.text: " + drop.text)
    console.log("-----------------------")

    for (var i = 0; i < drop.formats.length; ++i) {
        console.log(drop.formats[i] + ": " + drop.getDataAsString(drop.formats[i]))
    }
}
```

that will give the following information (dragged and dropped the Qt logo image from the documentation):

```
qml: drop.urls: https://doc.qt.io/
qml: drop.html: <html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><img src="https://doc.qt.io/style/qt-logo-documentation.svg" alt="Qt documentation"><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
qml: drop.text: https://doc.qt.io/
qml: -----------------------
qml: application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragContext": 
qml: application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="DragImageBits": ?
qml: application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="chromium/x-renderer-taint": 
qml: application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileGroupDescriptorW": 
qml: application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="FileContents": 
qml: text/x-moz-url: h
qml: text/uri-list: https://doc.qt.io/
qml: application/x-qt-windows-mime;value="UniformResourceLocatorW": h
qml: text/plain: https://doc.qt.io/
qml: text/html: <html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><img src="https://doc.qt.io/style/qt-logo-documentation.svg" alt="Qt documentation"><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Among the available properties (including those obtained through formats), there is no raw image data. `drop.html` provides useful information about the address of the dropped image, but is it really the only way to get an image is to download it using the received link?

I also thought about whether it is possible to somehow get `QMimeData` so that it can call [imageData()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmimedata.html#imageData) and get the image in this way. I found a similar transfer of mime data to QML from the Krita developers (see [DeclarativeMimeData* const m_data](https://invent.kde.org/graphics/krita/-/blob/master/libs/libqml/plugins/draganddrop/DeclarativeDragArea.h), which they define as `Q_PROPERTY`), but I'm not sure that this is the easiest, and most importantly, working way.

So to sum it up, is there a way to get the raw data of an image dragged and dropped from a browser or the image itself as a `QImage`, using the standard QML `DropArea` component?

Comment: I don't really get the requirements. If it is only about to show an image that got dragged from the browser to your application, you can use the URL provided by the DragEvent and assign it to the `source` property of a QML Image. It is capable of showing remote URLs. If you actually want to download an image you need to use C++ QNetworkRequest and write some kind of interface for QML.

Comment: The goal is precisely to create a file from the dropped image, and this question is primarily about whether the DropArea provides raw image data for this (or as a QImage). Apparently, apart from the url, the image itself should not be provided (which is logical, the size can be very large), so I really need to use QNetworkRequest.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Before going to C++ and QNetworkAccessManager there are extra things you can do in QML to validate whether you indeed have an image.

The following demonstrates that we can either:

1. check the contents of the `drop.formats`
2. run an XMLHTTPRequest "HEAD" request

The latter is particularly useful because we can infer the mime type from the content type, and, if available, determine how big something is by reading the content length.

Also, if you wish to have an in-memory copy of the image, you can create a second XMLHttpRequest. This time you can set "GET" and set responseType to "arraybuffer".

```
            DropArea {
                id: dropArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                property url dropUrl
                property string contentType
                property bool isImage
                property int contentLength
                onDropped: function (drop) {
                    console.log("formats: ", JSON.stringify(drop.formats));
                    if (!drop.hasUrls) return;
                    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    dropUrl = drop.urls[0];
                    console.log("dropUrl: ", dropUrl);
                    xhr.open("HEAD", dropUrl, false);
                    xhr.send();
                    contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                    console.log("contentType: ", contentType);
                    isImage = contentType.startsWith("image/");
                    contentLength = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") ?? 0;
                    console.log("contentLength: ", contentLength);
                    let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr2.open("GET", dropUrl, false);
                    xhr2.responseType = "arraybuffer";
                    xhr2.send();
                    let data = xhr2.response;
                    console.log(data.byteLength);
                }
            }
```